# Domain resolving to lan ip address under dynamic dns and tomato

Tags: home-server, tomato, dynamic-dns

I have recently begun hosting my personal website under a home server using dynamic dns.

The domain is registered under Godaddy, and ZoneEdit as the dynamic dns manager. Everything works well till it reaches my router (with Tomato v1.28). The domain (lets say example.com) translates as follows:

```
http://www.example.com ---> http://192.168.1.200/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

instead of

```
http://www.example.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

I'm using the in built port forwarding feature in Tomato. The above ofcourse works on a machine connected to the local network.

This happens only when attempting to access the root url i.e. www.example.com, but www.example.com/blog or www.example.com/wiki retain the domain name.

I'm using a centos server, with apache.

Comment: The problem wasn't in either the router or in setting the hostname, but in the LocalSettings.php of mediawiki I'm using. Fixing the servername in the file fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

Your webserver is redirecting but has not been configured with a DNS name so uses it's internal IP_address in the redirection response.

Configure the domain name in the webserver software.

Answer (score 2):

That has got nothing to do with your router. You need to add your domain name to the web-server. If you are using apache, then you may have to add your domain name to the vhosts file. Read more here: http://support.aiso.net/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=243

Comment: I have configured my hosts file, host and apache conf file, but the problem keeps recurring.